# Trigger question about object SignupRequest

Tags: apex, trigger, web2lead

I'm having a question about some tutorial I've been reading.

I'm trying to create my licenses through a web-to-lead, following this article http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2013/06/using-the-new-signup-api-to-manage-your-leads-and-deployments.html

I'm stuck in the beginning of it where it talks about SignupRequest object. In a TMO, isn't this a standard object? I seem to be unable to find it and add custom objects, maybe I must follow another way. Also, when I'm creating the trigger, from what I understand, I must select the option where it says "SignupRequest" or something similar right? The problem is I can't see this option.

Comment: I don't have a TMO to test in, but it's definitely a standard object; I can confirm it with an error from `System.debug(Schema.SignupRequest.SObjectType)`, which returns "Entity is not org-accessible", meaning it exists but I don't have access to it. Make sure you're in the right org. You can add custom fields to it, and also assign a trigger to it, as the article demonstrates. Most likely, you're attempting to access this object from the LMO or your DE org, neither of which will have access to this object.

Comment: Yes, I had actually tried to create this object in an apex class and it gave me the exact same error. I tried to check if I had to "enable" the object but had no success thus far. Appreciate for the answer, at least it cleared my doubts.

Comment: You don't need to enable it, it'll be available in your TMO automatically. If you haven't logged a case for a TMO, you don't have a TMO.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. It's just that I was indicated that the org in question was the TMO one, so now I must contact the owners.

Comment: I've just had a DE org enabled as a TMO and I also cannot see the Signup Request API / Object. I've raised another case to see if this needs to be enabled. I'll update this question once I get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SignupRequest is a standard object.
It will get enabled only in the Business org.
Business org generally is the paid enterprise org, more important is the fact that its is the org where LMA app is installed.

Try figuring out the Business LMA org and look there.
I think its not GA, so a partner support case is required to enable this object API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the SignupRequest standard object is only available to a Partner in their Business Org where the License Management App is installed. And the partner must file a case in the Partner Community to get it enabled.